# Showing that $ \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \theta + \mathbb{Z}\theta^2$ is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, determinant, integral-domain

I have  the following question,

> Let $\theta $ be the root of qubic equation $\theta^3 + \theta + 1 =
>  0$. Let  $ D = \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z} \theta + \mathbb{Z}\theta^2 =
>  \{a + b\theta + c\theta^2 \, : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Show that $D$
> is an integral domain.

It is easy to see that $D$ is a commutative ring with unity, so it is enough to show that there are no zero divisors. Let $a + b\theta + c\theta^2 $ and $x+ y\theta + z\theta^2 \, $
be in $D$. We assume that $a + b\theta + c\theta^2  \ne 0$ and we need to show that $x =  y = z = 0$ when $(a + b\theta + c\theta^2 ) \cdot (x + y\theta + z\theta^2) = 0$.

Expanding this we get the following system of equation

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
ax- cy -bz &= 0 \\ 
bx+ (a-c)y + (-c-b)z &= 0\\ 
c x+b y+ (a-c)z &= 0 
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$
To show $x = y = z = 0$ we need to show that the determinant of the  matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -c & -b \\
b & a -c & -c-b \\
c & b & a -c
\end{pmatrix} is non zero. Does there exist integers $a,b$ and $c$ such that at least one of them in non zero and the determinant is $0$? I suspect that the determinant is always non zero but I am not able to prove it. If any two of $a,b,c$ are zero then we can easily see that the determinant is non zero but how to do in general?

Comment: Are you familiar with minimal polynomials or quotient rings?

Comment: Yes I am aware of minimal polynomials. @Bill Dubuque  how it is related here

Comment: You could try to show that $D\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$ (via the isomorphism theorem for rings) and that $x^3+x+1\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is prime (for this you only need that it has no zeroes in $\mathbb{Z}$, which follows by basic calculus).

Comment: If $(a+b\theta+c\theta^2)(x+y\theta+z\theta^2)=(\theta^2+\theta+1)p(\theta)$, then the $\gcd$ of $\theta^3+\theta+1$ and one of $a+b\theta+c\theta^2$, or $x+y\theta+z\theta^2)$ must have positive degree. That $\gcd$ would be a non-trivial factor of $\theta^3+\theta+1$ (in $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$). Therefore, it is sufficient to show that no such factorization exists. If it did then this polynomial would have a rational root, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Severin Schraven So that $D$ is an integral domain? Perfect. I did not think about this.

Comment: I am thinking that we can generalize this by  taking $x ^ 3 + ax+ 1$ such that  $x ^ 3 + ax + 1$  is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Is it possible?

Comment: You say that $\theta$ is *the* root of $x^3+x+1=0$. Then isn't $D$ a subring of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: when evaluating $p(x)=x^3+x+1$, doing a substitution into $\mathbb F_2$ is easiest-- in $\mathbb F_2$ we have $p(1)=p(0)=1$ and is irreducible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3+x+1$.  By the rational root test, the only possible rational roots of $f(x)$ are $\pm 1$, which are not roots.  Therefore $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.  Since $f(x)$ is also primitive in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ it follows that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.  Since $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is a UFD, $f(x)$ is a prime element so $(f)$ (the ideal generated by $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$) is a prime ideal, so the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f)$ is an integral domain.  Elementary enough?